# Game token in Solidity ETH

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereumjs, nft

I'm designing a game that will run NFT.
In the last few days I've been studying a lot about Solidity and I managed to understand a lot (I even followed the CryptoZombie classes).

But I have a big doubt about the prize, the token that will be used as a reward.

My questions are beginners, I'm sorry, but I couldn't find anything on the internet that would help me, if you have any content you can share I'll be happy.

My questions:

1st For me to create a rewards token, for example, the SLP that axie has, will I create this contract in ERC720 or 721?

2nd How do I create the token like the SLP? And how do I give my players this prize token? Looking at Axie's systematics for example, at some point I use the "claim" option on their website, I believe that the SLP is saved in the database and after the action it starts to exist in the ETH portfolio, right?

3rd I want to put items to be sold that will use the token as currency, I believe this action is "burn" because we want to burn the currency in exchange for items, how is this done? Do you have an example to point me to?

4th Another question I would need to have different contracts for my SLP example currency, for the characters that will be NFT, for the Items and etc...? Is this analyzing the long term and giving the possibility of growth?

5º Contracts are immutable, my question would be, for example, I want in the future to have the marketplace option in the game, however, do I need to create these types of contracts now? Or can I create a contract in the future called marketplace and thus create the rules and etc of it?

I know these are starter questions but I couldn't find answers, thank you community for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answer to all of your questions but can provide for the 5th one. You don't need to have such a contract now but when you do you would have redeployed the solution on-chain again.